# When Opportunity stage is won then that stage status should be locked

Tags: customization

When Opportunity stage is Won. Then that opportunity stage can able to make freeze..So once won we can't able to change that stage status to others.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  What exactly is your question.  This seems to be an idea that you might want to post on the idea exchange. If you are asking if you can accomplish this through customization, then please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja I respectfully disagree. Oftentimes on SFSE, the question isn't "clear" simply because the asker doesn't know what features the platform supports. Since there is a means to achieve the desired goal without an feature request, it seems that that may be the right path to go.

Comment: I completely agree with what you are saying, my point was just the question wasn't clear.  That's all.

Comment: not easy, but i could understand it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this through a validation rule, located at: Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Validation Rules.

```
PRIORVALUE(IsWon)
```

This will prevent any edit to the record at all, once it has been set to Won.

```
AND(NOT(IsWon), PRIORVALUE(IsWon))
```

This will prevent any edit that would cause it to no longer be won (i.e. changing the stage).